# function is getting executed for a invalid argument

Tags: r

Below is the function created to format number.

```
format_number <- function(num, format_flag = "yes"){
  if(format_flag == "yes"){
    num <- paste0(num/100,"%")
  } else if (format_flag == "no"){
    num <- num
  } 
  return(num)
}
```

However, when I execute `format_number(3,2)`, the answer is `3`. Basically it should show an error right? Because 2 is not a valid input. Please advice

Comment: Where in the code you have written that 2 (or any number) is not a valid input?

Comment: 2 is definitely a valid input here. Why would you think it wouldn't be

Comment: `3` is neither `yes` nor `no`, so the `if`-statement does nothing and the funciton simply returns `num` without modifiing it. To return an error, just use an `else { stop("inavlid format_flag")}` or something similar.

Comment: R interpreter does not force variables to be of specific type.  So you can assign a string to a variable and then later assign a numeric (another type) to the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

2 is valid input. but in your function none of "if" statement will satisfied because 2!='yes' and 2!='no' , then the original value of 'num' will return which is 3.